# What are the peak hours here?

Tags: discussion

I'll admit I frequent UX.SE through out my day and then I go to sleep and wake up to more questions and answer activity than my whole day of stalking.

I'm guessing a majority of us don't live in the west coast of the US and live in europe or something.

**What are the peak hours here?**

Answer (score 2):

Covered here:

[What is the best time to ask questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/best-time-to-ask-questions)

This is a different site topic, of course, but I'd expect people's time to be similarly distributed here, statistically speaking.